I am needing a fairly customized photo gallery. The gallery needs to have only one image at a time, and 3 different text boxes per image
I am building a website on Squarespace, but this question is about HTML
On Desktop:
I need a gallery that has a single image between a top and bottom line that are close to their respective edges of the page. On Desktop the image should fill so the top touches the bottom of the top line, and the bottom of each image should touch the top of the bottom line, and be centered on the page. There should be a "orgnaization" line at 20 px and text aligned left on the bottom left, just above the line, on top of it should be a "sirname" text that should be left aligned and 20 px, on top of that line should be a "description" line that is aligned left and the vertical align should be bottom. It should also be 20px. The description line shouldn't wrap at about 25% of the screen size.
In the end the gallery needs to be set up so that when hovering on the left side of the gallery the mouse turns into a left arrow, and when hovering on the right side of the gallery the mouse turns into a right arrow. When clicked these will help the visitor navigate left or right, populating a new image and the 3 new text boxes.
On Mobile:
Everything is the same except that the image should be set to fill about 80% of the screen width and be centered.
Also, rather than left and right arrows, swiping left and right are what is needed to navigate the gallery.
So far I have this code in a code injector:
   <style>
@font-face {
    font-family: redacted;
    scr:    "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/66018fd7c738c4455473aac1/t/660c276cc7e29e04bbffe27c/1712072557077/redacted";
    }
 #imagecontent {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    align-content: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 97%;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 95;
    }
 #description {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 93%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    font-family: diagraph-regular;
    color: #654434;
    z-index: 525;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    }
 #sirname {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 92%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: diagraph-regular;
    color: #654434;
    z-index: 550;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    }
  #organization {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 95%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: diagraph-regular;
    color: #D2C1AF;
    z-index: 575;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    }

 </style>
 <div>
  <div id="imagecontent"></div>

  <div id="sirname"></div>

  <div id="organization"></div>

  <div id="description"></div>

  <button id="previous">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>

<script>

const content = [
  {
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/66018fd7c738c4455473aac1/t/660b77e58757ef3b2bbbaf65/1712027622432/Image+Filler+Horizontal.png",
    sirname: "Jane Doe",
    organization: "Adams Inc.",
    description: "This photo is a great photo showing great things"
  },
  {
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/66018fd7c738c4455473aac1/t/660b77e8666c3540780e238a/1712027624538/Image+Filler+Vertical.png", 
    sirname: "Aaron Smith",
    organization: "123 Company",
    description: "This photo is an okay photo showing mediocre things"
  },
  {
    image: "image3.jpg",
    sirname: "Jones", 
    organization: "XYZ Corp",
    description: "This is a photo"
  }
];

let currentIndex = 0;

function showContent() {
  const currentContent = content[currentIndex];

  document.getElementById("imagecontent").innerHTML = `<img src="${currentContent.image}">`;
  document.getElementById("sirname").innerHTML = currentContent.surname;
  document.getElementById("organization").innerHTML = currentContent.organization; 
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = currentContent.description;
}

document.getElementById("previous").addEventListener("click", () => {
  currentIndex--;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = content.length - 1; 
  }
  showContent();
});

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", () => {
  currentIndex++;
  if (currentIndex >= content.length) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  showContent(); 
});

showContent();

</script>

And this code in sitewide CSS:
/*main page*/
        /*desktop Changes*/
/*HTML to Fit Page*/
#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1711996639022_49231 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

It is doing some of what I want, but I can't seem to get the image to auto-expand to fill 97% of the height of the screen size. I'm not sure yet what strategy I will use to get the navigation to work. I was thinking to try making the buttons very large and entirely transparent on the left and right sides, and setting a hover effect to change the cursor.
This is the current test display:

These are the end goals 

I would use grid instead absolute or fixed positioning . You may eventually use a fixed positionning for the main container. Nowdays grid or flex are efficient. here is an example of your code without positionning :  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGJapyd

Can you explain how this would work? I'm not sure I understand how it would layout in the end. I have added two images to the question to clarify exactly how the page should display on a screen of any size over 749px.

You have to define a grid (so many rows and columns and size them via auto, Xfr or any fixed values), then dispatch the content inside the grid inside a cell  a spanning through many. You should read some tutorials about grid to master where you want to layout each element inside the grid generated. no position needed and top or left becomes a row/grid position

I have updated the code to be accurate at this site:
link
I just can't seem to get the bottom line to rise up to be the same distance from the bottom as the top line is from the top, or the image to only completely fill the space between the lines in terms of height. If you have the time, would you be able to take a look and help me figure out why?

Correction on the link, I didn't realize I couldn't save my edits on that editor, here it is: https://codepen.io/nathan-rose-solutions/pen/MWRXNMO

hello, you have used many times the same selectors , so position in the grid and styles are reset many times too . I do not think you need spacer either. maybe doing 2 grids and a markup with a bit of semantics might help you to sort out styling the grid and the contents . here is another example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZEZjQGO
